# building OpenCV cannot provide cv2.so - fresh ubuntu installation

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I made the following steps:

1- Installed Anaconda and added link to anaconda bin in the .bashrc

2- Made an new env called py27 and activated it

3- Installed numpy in this env

4- Now I am trying to build opencv but it does not generate the cv2.so file. In the cmake step, it does not show numpy version either. I installed the dev headers but still did not had any impact

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

While trying to fix my issues, I used `make clean` instead of removing the folder `build`. Removing instead cleared the cache (the reason of my issue most probably) so the right commands provided the right outputs!